# This import is black listed , import a sub-module instead

Tags: angular, angular-observable

**Query 1**

Below is the import section of my app component with observable import that got the code working.

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
```

But, The IDE shows ["rxjs/Rx" ] as blacklisted usage but still it gives me the desired output using Observable.interval(1000) on browser console. Why is IDE saying this as blacklisted usage :( while it works!

**Query 2**

The initial code that I attempted was as below but it throws error on console and do not give me desired interval output to console.

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
```

**Console Error Output**

> rxjs_Observable__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.Observable.interval is not a function
>       at AppComponent.push../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.ngOnInit (app.component.ts:15)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9250)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10514)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10476)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11109)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11069)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11061)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10458)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11351)

Which is the right approach, request suggestion.

Comment: What is your `rxjs` version?

Answer (score 4):

- First of all, `Never import from rxjs/Rx, because it'll include every single operator, static method, scheduler, and utility that you probably don't need.` If you don't care about the bundle size, then you can import using `rxjs/Rx`.
- Are you sure you are importing `Observable` only once. Check if it is imported twice from the main-module and the sub-module. It is possible that your project is accessing some `global version` of `Observable` that isn't the same Observable that the `intervals()` method is added to with `'rxjs/add/observable/interval'`. This can happen  if you accidentally have two versions of `rxjs` bundled in with your app, one that's somewhere being made global and a different one you're importing here.
- If it still doesn't work, can you try importing `interval` in the static context in your module. Use `import { interval } from 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';`